# Exporting from an SDF database file to MySQL, on JSP

Tags: mysql, windows, jsp, phpmyadmin, sdf

I have an SDF database that is updated regularly by an external application, and I use SDFBrowser to currently export that data into a CSV file and then import that data into MySQL database using PHP MyAdmin.

I want this job to run every day at a given time, say 2 am, automatically. SDF Browser does not have a command line interface that I can write a batch file with, so that is out of question.

Can you suggest the best way to do this? It will be running on a server, so AutoIT scripts were considered and discarded too, the server will be locked, with only remote logins possible if necessary, or it will just keep serving pages.

Thanks in advance.